# Python, count down timer that doesn't sleep

Tags: python, multithreading, countdown

I am new to python and i am trying to make a countdown timer on a button click. But i would like this countdown timer to start its countdown and place the current countdown value in the text area. Also i need the rest of the application to not sleep while this countdown is running. So far it will output the countdown in the console but will freeze the rest of the application. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import threading
import thread

class App:


    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.getvalue = Button(frame, text="Get the Text Area", command=self.thevalue)
        self.getvalue.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.text_area = Entry()
        self.text_area.pack(side=RIGHT)


    def thevalue(self):
        print "In the value"
        try:
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.print_time("I am in print_time"))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
        except:
            print "Error: unable to start thread"

    def print_time(self,bleh):
        print bleh
        print "The text area value is %s" % self.text_area.get()
        boom=5
        while boom >0:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.text_area.delete(0, END)
            self.text_area.insert(0, boom)
            print(boom)
            boom -=1

root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
threading.Thread(target=self.print_time("I am in print_time"))
```

This will not do what you want it to do. What happens here is that the function `self.print_time` is called and its return value is then passed to the constructor of `threading.Thread`.

You need to create the thread like this:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=self.print_time, args=("I am in print_time",))
```

Comment: oh ok great thank you! looks like i have more reading to do :D

Comment: Just remember that `something()` will call the function immediately, while `something` is just a reference to it :)